# No matching Localization found for URL For Certain Pages in Website

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-1.5

I am setting up DXA 1.5 Application with SDL Web 8.1. I did all the Services Mapping, and Topology Manager Mapping. When publishing done from CMS, and hit th site on browser, most of the pages are working fine, but I get `No matching Localization found for URL`error on few pages.

The error still persists even if I republish the page. However, if I restart the DXA Web Application in IIS, the pages start to show up on the website.

Any idea why this happened? Did anyone else faced similar kind of issue? Any help will be highly appreciated to get to the root cause of this.

Please let me know, if any further information is required.

Comment: That sounds strange! Localization/Publication URL resolving is unrelated to items being published or not. Would be nice to get more clarity on when this happens.  Please check the Content Service log file when it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the issue resolved. The issue was with the way, Topology Manager was mapping the Topology Settings in Discovery DB. I had two CD Servers, and each Discovery Service was mapped to respective Discovery DB. So, when I was running the Topology Manager Scripts, the Topology Settings was going into only one Discovery DB, not another. That is why we need to use only one Discovery DB for both Discovery Services and one Broker DB for Publishing, as Deployer URL is mapped in Deployer Capability in Discovery DB, and that can only be one.

But still one question though, what if we need to publish to file systems of Multiple Web Servers. However, I did a workaround to overcome this, as it is required in our Project.

We are now using two Discovery DBs for each Discovery Services. When Toplogy Manager settings is done, Discovery DB for Service 1 gets updated. Then we take backup of that DB, and restore in DB of Discovery Service 2. Once DB is restored for Discovery Service 2, we are running `java -jar discovery-registration.jar forceSync` Command for Discovery Service 2. In this way, all Topology Manager Settings also go to Discovery DB, and the respective settings of Discovery Service 2 is also updated in DB. It resolved the issue in our project and now the sites are working absolutely fine on both servers.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the problem. However, your CIS configuration sounds bizarre to me!  Why would you want to have 2 DBs for one CD Environment? And do you really keep them in sync manually with DB backup/restore ?!

Comment: Agree, why not a single DB that both discovery services use?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue you might see when there is new item((multimedia files) published with the page. As DXA use caching at 2 levels it might be a case that page is seeing that newly added multimedia item and try to get the multimedia item while because of cache application is still not able to find it.

In application debug log file you can see the items throwing such exception. If this is not the case then you can see the reason in debug log.